# Java HttpComponents not using original URL for GET request

Tags: java, http, apache-httpcomponents

It seems that If I have this code here...

```
someGetMethod = 
    new HttpGet("http://www.website.com/blah/Action?test1=1&Test2=2");
```

I am oddly enough getting this http request header generated. Notice how `Action` is missing and the URL is just wrong

```
GET /blah/?test1=1&Test2=2
```

Does anyone understand why this bug is happening in HttpComponents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is a bug. It is in the consturctor call `new HttpGet("URI...")`.

This fixes the issue...

```
HttpGet someGet new HttpGet();
someGet.setURI(new URI(url));
```